# Error when trying to insert entity using .NET Core, Entity Framework and SQL Server on Azure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, azure, asp.net-core

In development phase I was using SQLite and all works fine when I only set Key attribute to Id field. No I'm trying to use SQL Server on Azure. I manage to build database but when I try to add first entity I get this error.

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception
>   for details. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error
>   occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for
>   details.
>   ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'MSPL.dbo.Users'; column does not allo w
>   nulls. INSERT fails.

Here is my current database context configuration. I'm using code first.

```
public class MultiSourcePlaylistContext : DbContext
    {
        public MultiSourcePlaylistContext(DbContextOptions<MultiSourcePlaylistContext> options) :base(options)
        { 
        }
        public DbSet<Track> Tracks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Playlist> Playlists { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        { 
            builder.Entity<Track>()
                .HasOne(track=>track.Playlist)
                .WithMany(playlist => playlist.Tracks)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            builder.Entity<Playlist>()
                .HasOne(track=>track.Owner)
                .WithMany(user => user.Playlists) 
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            base.OnModelCreating(builder); 
        } 
    }
```

Here is one example Entity

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string Fname {get;set;}
        public string Lname {get;set;}
        public string FileFolder{get;set;}
        public ICollection<Playlist> Playlists { get; set; }

    }
```

So the different is that I started to use SQL Server instead of SQLite. I already added DatabaseGenerated attribute even that I understand that if Entity has Id or entityNameId fields it is automatically Primary field. My goal is to get id automatically set when new entity is inserted.

Here is my service configuration from Startup.cs

```
if(CurrentEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                var connection = Configuration["Development:SqliteConnectionString"];
                services.AddDbContext<MultiSourcePlaylistContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlite(connection)
                );
            }
            else
            {
                var connection = Configuration["Production:SqlServerConnectionString"];
                services.AddDbContext<MultiSourcePlaylistContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(connection)
                );
            }
```

Here is lines where I made insert

```
public void PostUser(User user)
        {
            _context.Users.Add(user);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Here is Create script for User table from SQL Management Studio. it shows that there is no Identity set to Id field. I will try to remove all attributes from Entities.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
    [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [FileFolder] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Fname] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Lname] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Password] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Username] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)

GO
```

Here is more log before exception. There is that critical log which shows my entity's properties. I noticed that there is no Id in the Insert command.

> TokenAuthController[0]
>         {"Id":0,"Username":"MyUsername","Password":"AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEOtXeLCECSRSINe9+kOexywYeP+E/o1nh2hYNO5EG1OBu4eL+7ult2PGOFDs8r+CwQ==","
>   Fname":"MyName","Lname":"MyLastName","FileFolder":"184d0857-31ef-4bd5-aeb1-51934e98f670","Playlists":null}
>   info:
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalCommandBuilderFactory[1]
>         Executed DbCommand (728ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (Size = 4000), @p1='?' (Size = 4000), @p2='?' (Size = 4000), @p3='?' (Size = 4 000),
>   @p4='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>         SET NOCOUNT ON;
>         INSERT INTO [Users] ([FileFolder], [Fname], [Lname], [Password], [Username])
>         VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4);
>         SELECT [Id]
>         FROM [Users]
>         WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [Id] = scope_identity();

Comment: You forgot to post the code where you actually create a new User and call SaveChanges.. Also, you don't need to add attributes to the Id property. Entity Framework has conventions and will automatically pick it up that Id is the PK of the table.

Comment: If the ```Id``` field is of type ```long```, how can it be you're trying to insert null? I would at least expect a value of 0 or -1.

Comment: Hmm. I will try to remove all attirbutes from Id fields.

Comment: The attribute itself is not the issue. I just pointed out that EF catchs that by convetion, so you don't have to polute your models. Can you check the table on Azure to see if the Id column has Identity =true? Also, can you run on Local SQL Server and debug? Rick van den Bosch had a good point.. the value should be 0.

Comment: Did you checked on SQL Server if the `Id` column in your table `User` is an identity column ?

Comment: that null things is true stange. it's not long?-type its long which can't be null.

Comment: I will check next is there Identity set.

Comment: There was not IDENTITY set to Id in the Azure database. Could it be any different when using local db than azure? I have debugging from C# but I don't have experience on debugging SQL. But I can show you log from .Net Core console.

Comment: Did you publish the schema you've defined in code to the Azure database?

Comment: What that mean "publish the schema to the Azure"?

Comment: And Id is null because there is no Id in the INSERT like you can see from my extra log. Should EF add Id to or is it SQL Servers job to increment Id?

Comment: It should be SQL Server's job. Rebuild your table and set Id column identity

Comment: Do you mean by using Management Studio? That I was thinking of also but I also think that EF should manage this by itself (set Identity to Id field). This is working solution but I think this is not the best one.

Comment: Can anyone say why EF didn't add Identity to Id fields?

Comment: Can you post your Migration file? Two possible reasons I see for this: The latest migration wasn't applied on Azure OR the migration itself is messed up. If you post it here, we can see if is correct. You can also run the update command with --verbose to see the sql that is being generated..

Comment: Thank you jqgrassi for your question. There is for example this line in migration Id = table.Column<long>(nullable: false).Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true). Then I think why this is there and I remember that I run my add migration command without -e Production parameter. So migration was for sqlite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was generating migration wihout -e Production parameter. I use that parameter in Startup.cs `if(CurrentEnvironment.IsDevelopment())`
So I was running SQLite migration to SQL server.

So my Entities was correct whole time I just forget to run migration command against Production DB. So now my Id field in migration looks like this:

```
Id = table.Column<long>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
```

when my User Entity is like this:

```
public class User
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string Fname {get;set;}
        public string Lname {get;set;}
        public string FileFolder{get;set;}
        public ICollection<Playlist> Playlists { get; set; }

    }
```

Here is my commands to Production ie. my SQL Server database.

> dotnet ef migrations add newdatabase -e Production
>
> dotnet ef database update -e Production

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, You could use the `Key` attribute if the entity does have its own primary key but you want to name the property something other than classnameID or ID. Also, you could use the `DatabaseGenerated` attribute on your property specifies that the primary key, and specify `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` for the value generated on add or `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed` for the value generated on add or update. For more details, you could refer to [Generated Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties).

According to your description, I have checked it with my .NET Core web application (.NET Core 1.0). Here are my test, you could refer to them.

**For SQLite:**

[image]

[image]

**For SQL Server DB:**

[image]

[image]

The related Nuget packages:[image]